Am I using the fisher.test() function incorrectly? Can't replicate p-value found in research paper
I've been trying to replicate the results of this research paper (The Tale of Cochran’s Rule: My Contingency Table has so Many Expected Values Smaller than 5, What Am I to Do? by Kroonenberg and Verbeek) but my numbers simply aren't matching up with theirs. In the paper, they use the following contingency table:
                            Type of Surgery
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Patient's state        None        A         B           Total
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Still alive             0          5         1             6
Passed away             3          1         2             6
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                   3          6         3             12

To make this claim about checking whether patient's state and type of surgery are independent:

"In your precarious state of health you discover that the exact test produces a pX2 of 0.12, in other words, the test for independence cannot be rejected."

and to make this claim about checking whether the types of surgeries are independent

"The table about the choice between two types of surgery (supposing that we could test independently of the previous test) has an X2 of 2.25, with pX2 = 0.46 and pχ2 = 0.13."

As you can see, they claim to be using a fisher's exact test to get their pX2 values (and a regular chi-square test for their pχ2 values) However, running the code below in R yields, for the first claim, a p-value of 0.0801 not 0.12. In fact, I can only get a value around 0.12 if I run a chi-squared test with a simulated p-value:
disease <- matrix(c(0, 5, 1, 3, 1, 2), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(disease) <- c("None", "A", "B")
rownames(disease) <- c("Still alive", "Passed Away")


fisher.test(disease, conf.int = FALSE)
chisq.test(disease, simulate.p.value = TRUE)

Am I using the fisher.test() function incorrectly? Is there something I'm missing here?

This should perhaps be a comment, but I can't see that you're doing anything wrong, either in R or in a quick skim of the paper. There is no continuity correction option (a common cause of mismatches/confusion in contingency table analysis), and no asymptotic approximations being used by default. (If we force the use of an asymptotic approximation by running fisher.test(disease, conf.int = FALSE, hybrid = TRUE, hybridPars = c(1, 1,1)), the p-value is 0.062.) I would consider contacting the corresponding author.
For what it's worth this online calculator gives the same answer that you got with R's fisher.test():


I do not see any error in your calculations and I am getting the same results as you when I run the various tests at issue (see below for closest result to their reported result).  I think the most likely explanation here is that the authors accidentally used the Pearson chi-squared test instead of the Fisher test.  These use different test statistics so it is natural that they give different results.  You have done enough preliminary work here to warrant contacting the authors to ask for clarification if that is something you want to follow up.
#Compute p-value from Pearson chi-squared test (via simulation)
set.seed(1)
chisq.test(disease, simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 10^7)


        Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 1e+07 replicates)

data:  disease
X-squared = 6, df = NA, p-value = 0.1234

